# Getting the record ID just added with mysql prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm inserting a record using PDO and saving the result in `$result` which I use as a boolean

```
$result = $addRecord->execute();

if ($result){ 
   //add successful
} else {
   //add unsuccessful
}
```

I'd like to also get the record `id` just added. In the table, each record has an `auto_incremented` field called `id`. I tried doing this

```
$new_id = $result['id'];
```

but it seems `$result` doesn't actually hold the record added. Can someone confirm this and how would I then access the record just added?

**Note that several people may be adding to the same table at the same time, so I need something really accurate.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PDO::lastInsertId()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) should work.

EDIT: (did not see your other part)

MySQL mantains the last insert id on a http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html">*per-connnection* basis. So if something else inserts a row it should only return unexpected results if that query was executed using the same connection (like a persistent connection).

Comment: But as I said in the question, what if several people are adding at the same time. Wouldn't that return an id possibly inserted by someone else? See last line in my question.

Comment: @dmontain: No. It's per connection. Each request would have its own connection, so this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @dmontain Added information regarding concurrancy, including a link to the MySQL documentation.